# amp-img what are the attribute:attribution for?

Tags: amp-html

The amp-img has the atrribute: attribution.
For what ist this? On mobile device are no mouse-over.
Is ther a plan to add this note to the picture?
I ask about to use this field for CC-Picture with share attribution. Here in Europe (may be around the world) it must be labeld close to the picture the name of the author.

Answer (score 3):

When using an image in `amp-html`, `amp-img` includes attributes for denoting attribution via [attribution](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/builtins/amp-img.md) attribute.

> [**Attribution**](https://inquisitivehippo.com/2012/10/14/6-things-about-image-attribution/): This license lets others distribute, remix, tweak, and build upon your work, even commercially, as long as they credit you for the original creation. This is the most accommodating of licenses offered. **Recommended for maximum dissemination and use of licensed materials**.

`attribution= "CC courtesy of AMP on Flicker"`

Comment: yes but it is still not visible on the page. Here in german (europe as well) it must be labeld closed to the picture not by looking in the source code. So my quetion is, is something planed to use this attribute to show on the frontend. Not only like alt/title="" with mouse over.